# Update the list object

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of object's  and i want to update the the object's Break property where breakflag=1 with its next and previous record.

```
class EmployeeHour 
{
   int recordID{get;set;}
   string Break{get;set;}
   DateTime TimeIn {get;set;}
   DateTime TimeOut {get;set;}
   int BreakFlag{get;set;}
}

List<EmployeeHour> listEH=(from item in employeeHoursList
                      where item.BreakFlag==1     
                        select item).Foreach(itme=>item.Break=(employeeHoursList[i].Timeout-employeeHoursList[i].TimeIn).ToString()).ToList();
```

So here i just want set the break property with the Time diff. between TimeIn and  TimeOut only for those objcet whoes breakflag is one. and TimeOut of that object where BeakFlag ==1 and TimeIn next to that object in the list.

Comment: Linq is for querying not updating data. BTW `ForEach` is not from Linq

Comment: What do you mean by "update with its next and previous record"?

Comment: Do you alway have next and previous record? What if first or last record have BreakFlag equal to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
List<EmployeeHour> listEH=
    (from item in employeeHoursList
     where item.BreakFlag == 1     
     select item).ToList();
listEH.ForEach(item => item.Break = (item.TimeOut - item.TimeIn).ToString());
```

This will modify the current `item.Break` with the current item's `.TimeOut` and `.TimeIn`.

---

**Update** from your updated question it seems like what want is to modify `item.Break` using either the previous or the next item in the list. In this case you probably shouldn't use Linq or a `ForEach` at all. A simple `for` loop would be cleaner (assuming `employeeHoursList` is a `List<T>`, array, or similar):

```
for(var i = 0; i < employeeHoursList.Count; i++)
{
    if (employeeHoursList[i].BreakFlag == 1 && (i + 1) < employeeHoursList.Count) 
    {
        employeeHoursList[i].Break = (employeeHoursList[i].TimeOut - employeeHoursList[i + 1].TimeIn).ToString()
    }
}
```